# Logical AND implementation in x86_64 Linux assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, fasm, logical-and

I'm trying to implement logical NOT and logical AND
in assembly, I did logical NOT already using `x < 1`
but I can't think of how to implement AND, I can use
binary and but that's broken for negative numbers (it
assumes -1 is `true`) and it doesn't make any sense
when NOT obviously works because `-1 < 1` would return `1`

So I'm confused, how could I do it, any known implementation
which I could use? I can't find it, been looking for a while

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard solution is to implement `a && b` as

```
if (a)
    return (b);
else
    return (0);
```

i.e. use a conditional jump.  On sufficiently new x86, you can also use a `cmov` instruction like this:

```
; assumes input in eax and ebx
mov ecx, eax    ; ecx = A
test ebx, ebx   ; B?
cmovnz ecx, ebx ; ecx = A ? B : A
```

Comment: This is even better of a solution, thank you!

Comment: ... and if you want to branch on the `a && b` result, `test ecx,ecx` / `jz` or `jnz`.  Or booleanize it to a 0/1 integer with `test ecx,ecx` / `setnz cl`.  Another answer suggests a more complicated way to get a 0/1, but this is more efficient.  x86-64 guarantees availability of cmovcc and setcc.

Answer (score 3):

This is an answer without jumps: Assume you want to compute logical AND of `RCX` and `RDX` and store it in `RAX` and you may use `RBX` (note that called functions usually must preserve `RBX`!).

```
xorl %eax, %eax   # RAX = 0
xorl %ebx, %ebx   # RBX = 0
cmpq %rcx, %rbx   # CF = (RCX != 0)
adcb %bl, %al     # RAX = (RCX != 0)
cmpq %rdx, %rbx   # CF = (RDX != 0)
adcb %bl, %al     # RAX = (RCX != 0) + (RDX != 0)
shrb $1, %al      # RAX = ((RCX != 0) + (RDX != 0)) >> 1
```

Now `RAX == 1` if and only if `RCX != 0` and `RDX != 0`; otherwise, `RAX == 0`

Comment: x86-64 guarantees the availability of `cmovc` and `setc %al`.  And `movzbl`.  So `test %rcx, %rcx` / `setnz %al` could replace the first cmp/adc.  Also, C `a && b` returns either `a` or `b`; you're implementing `(bool)(a && b)` to get a booleanized integer value instead of just a branch condition.  That might be useful, but in many cases overkill.  But if that is what you want, this isn't terrible.  Probably a test/`setnz %bl` / `and %ebx, %eax` would be better, though.  But wouldn't save any instructions if you want to avoid partial-register problems on all CPUs including old P6-family.

Comment: "The `&&` operator shall yield 1 if both of its operands compare unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0." (C99 standard, 6.5.13, 3)

Comment: Oops, my bad.  Of course normally you don't need that, if you're actually just going to branch on it you can `test %reg,%reg` / `jnz`. I think the best way to get the same result would be to build off of fuz's answer: mov/test/cmov, then booleanize that result if you want.  (e.g. with a possibly-non-zero value in RCX, `test %rcx,%rcx` / `setnz %al`).  For 5 total instructions.  Or 4 if you just want to get the `a && b` condition into FLAGS, with mov/test/cmov / `test`.

Comment: re: calling convention: right, RBX is not normally a good choice for a temporary; if you did need two, your first two function args would be in RDI and RSI (note the [linux] tag), and you can use RAX/RCX/RDX as temporaries.  And any of R8..R11, which are also call-clobbered in both x86-64 SysV and Windows x64.

Comment: Also, BTW, [fasm] syntax is an Intel syntax fairly close to NASM.  For register instructions, GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix` would also be compatible with it, but not the AT&T syntax you're using in this answer.  Not a big deal for readers who know both and can easily translate to/from AT&T syntax.

Comment: I was thinking about this some more.  If you want to play tricks with CF instead of using CMOV, another fun way is `xor eax,eax` / `sub rax, rcx` / `sbb rax, rax` (0 if RCX=0, else -1) / `and rax, rdx` (definitely 0 if RCX=0,  otherwise = RDX, which might or might not be non-zero.)  Hmm, so I've just re-invented cmp/CMOV less efficiently.  The final instruction can be `test rax,rdx` if you want.  (AMD CPUs treat `sbb same,same` as only dependent on CF, write-only on the integer reg.  But other CPUs don't, which is one reason I picked the register I just xor-zeroed)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is doing logical not twice on each input, and then doing a bitwise and (`AND` instruction).

Comment: True, that works, but a lot code, I'll wait a bit to see if I can get a better answer, if I can't find anything better or get any better answer I will use this and mark this as the solution :)

Comment: I went for this, thank you